# Can an iOS app access the subtitles or closed captions of a video in the device's Videos library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, subtitle, closed-captions

Is there a way to do this, by using the Media Player Framework or any other means?

I would like to build an app that allows the user to work with the subtitles of a store-bought video.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? Looking for the same thing. Will report back if i find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from iOS5, UIAccessibility protocol specifies a method UIAccessibilityIsClosedCaptioningEnabled() to get the value of Settings->Video->Closed Captioning switch value.